# Flask - use decorator and route param to render data with custom jinja2 tag

Tags: flask, decorator, jinja2, url-parameters

I'd like to add metadata tags to a Jinja template via combination of decorator and route param:

#### view:

```
@meta_tags(foo='bar', ping='pong')
@app.route('/some-route/<slug>')
def action(slug):
    return render_template('action.html')
```

#### template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Foo</title>
        {{ meta_tags }}
        <!-- 
        should render:
        <meta name="slug" content="[actual-slug]" />
        <meta name="foo" content="bar" />
        <meta name="ping" content="pong" />
        -->
    </head>
    ...
```

Goals:

- Render each of the `kwargs` into its own meta tag.
- Render the page-specific slug into another custom tag.

I realize one way to accomplish this involves registering with `@app.context_processor`, but then I also want to snag and use the dynamic `slug` part *and* create a custom `jinja` tag that'll render the `<meta>` html part.

What's an idiomatic Flask way to tackle? thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd rather decorate the function with it instead of just passing the meta `kwargs` to `render_template`? It would still be in the same area of the code, just different syntax.

Answer (score 10):

*This answer has been updated with improved information on routing and an example in keeping with the question*.

*There are now three examples:- simple, improved and elegant.*

**1.**

Simple solution is to use Jinja's **Block** content function in your *base.html* template's head section.

base.html:

```
<meta name="description" content="{% block description %}{% endblock %}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{% block keywords %}{% endblock %}" />
<meta name="author" content="{% block author %}{% endblock %}" />
<meta name="foo" content="{% block bar %}{% endblock %}" />
```

Then from any *child.html* you can set the block content, like so:

```
{% block description %}description from your child page.{% endblock %}
{% block keywords %}website, blog, coding{% endblock %}
{% block author %} {{ author.fullname }} {% endblock %}
{% block bar %}foo bar content{% endblock %}
```

***Updated...***

**2.**

**View.py**

```
@app.route('/some-route/<slug>')
def action(): 
   foo='bar'
   ping='pong'
   return render_template('child.html', foo, ping)
```

*Not sure why your meta_data is a decorator here, so changed my example.*

**base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    {% block metadata %}{% endblock %}
</head>
...
```

**child.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block metadata %}
   <meta name="meta_tags" content="{{ foo }}{{ping}}" />
   <meta name="description" content="{{ foo }}" />
   <meta name="keywords" content="{{ ping }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

**3.**

**Elegant & concise alternative:**

**View.py**

```
@app.route('/some-route/<slug>')
def action():
   metadata = {'keywords': 'foo', 'description': 'bar'}
   return render_template('child.html', metadata=metadata)
```

*N.B: base.html remains the same.*

**child.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block metadata %}
    <ul>
    {% for key, item in metadata.items() %}
       <meta name="{{ key }}" content="{{ item }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

More information can be found on Jinja templates, using Block content and template inheritance at: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#template-inheritance

Comment: could you explain the syntax to set the routing in the app with multiple parameters? I think the user asked how to serve meta tags dynamically, instead from the documentation of template inheritance it looks that you have child.html as static files.

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be to add blocks to your meta fields in base.html

The base.html file should look like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="slug" content="{% block slug %}{% if slug %}{{slug}}{%else%}Some sane defaults if needed{% endif %}{% endblock %}" />
</html>
```

Then in your view you should return as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('filename.html', slug=slug)
```

So if you pass slug in a render_template function it will be automatically added to your meta field.
Or you will be able to modify it in child template by adding

```
{% block slug %}value{% endblock %}
```